# Invoke a method from Main()

Tags: c#

I don't know what's wrong that I cannot call a method from `Main()`.
I don't know if its a bug in Visual Studio or I'm doing something wrong

This is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Security.Claims;
using Csharp_Projects.Constructs;

namespace Csharp_Projects
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ValueTypeContainingRefType();
        }

        class ShapeInfo
        {
            public string infoString;

            public ShapeInfo(string info)
            {
                infoString = info;
            }

            struct Rectangle
            {
                public ShapeInfo rectInfo;

                public int recTop, rectleft, rectBottom, rectRight;

                public Rectangle(string info, int top, int left, int Buttom, int Right)
                {
                    rectInfo = new ShapeInfo(info);
                    recTop = top;
                    rectBottom = Buttom;
                    rectRight = Right;
                    rectleft = left;
                }

                public void Display()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("string={0},top={1},Bottom={2},"+"left={3},Right={4}",rectInfo,recTop,rectBottom,rectRight,rectleft);
                }
                public static void ValueTypeContainingRefType()
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Creating r1");
                    Rectangle r1 = new Rectangle("First Rec", 10, 10, 50, 50);
                    Console.WriteLine("Assigning r2 to r1");
                    Rectangle r2 = r1;
                    Console.WriteLine("Change Values of r2");
                    r2.rectInfo.infoString = "This is new info!";
                    r2.rectBottom = 222;
                    r1.Display();
                    r2.Display();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> **the name "ValueTypeContainingRefType" does not exist in the current context.**

which absolutely nonsense since there is a method name `ValueTypeContainingRefType`

Comment: That is because the method you're trying to access is within another class.

Comment: The method you're trying to call is within a struct within another class and is also static.

Comment: When you think the compiler is doing something that's "absolutely nonsense", you're wrong 99.999999...% of the time.

Comment: you mean it never makes mistakes? never?

Comment: @Mohsen Very, very, *very* rarely.  You'll come across many thousands of people reporting correct behavior as bugs before you come across an actual bug in the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Rectangle` struct owns the method. Which is nested in `ShapeInfo`. Try this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ShapeInfo.Rectangle.ValueTypeContainingRefType();
}
```

You would also have to make `Rectangle` public.

Comment: You can't access `Rectangle` struct because it is private.

Comment: True. I will add that to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: I can't access it even if I make it public

Comment: Try `public struct Rectangle`. I just compiled your code with both of the mentioned changes and it works.